# VS Team Tester failed to run dynamic web test

Tags: visual-studio-2008, webtest

I have a Testing project that contains a csv file which a webtest uses to run against one of our projects.

For some reason, even though it is referenced correctly I receive the following error:

Could not run Web test 'SubmitBadData' on agent 'BLDSERVER': Could not access table 'BadData#csv' in data source 'BadData' of test '942b62a8-c123-4228-a6df-909ef009d62f': The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'BadData.csv'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

---

When I run this test locally, it executes just fine.  It only fails when I have our build server execute it.

Ideas?

**Reason for Closure:**

I must have recreated the webtest 10 times from scratch.  Each time it would work locally, but fail miserably when executed from the build server.  I just recreated it again... and it worked.

Oh well.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the csv file an embedded resource or a content file? Is it deployed in the same (relative) location on the build server as on the local machine?

Did you do everything that's mentioned in the walkthrough at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385833.aspx?

Comment: It's a content file.  The weird thing is that I have another test in this project which also pulls data from a csv (different one).  That one executes just fine.  The files are in the same directory.